# Spring p namespace showing "URI not registered" error on IntelliJ

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, namespaces, xml-namespaces

I want to use p namespace, but when I add `xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"` on `beans` tag, it shows me that URI is not registered.

I just ran the code even though I see that, and things worked fine,

but I don't want to see that error bulb coming up.

Is there a way to fix this?

+) Tried `Fetch external resource` but doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: mMake sure you have all Spring* bundled plugins enabled in Settings(Preferences) | Plugins.

Comment: Exactly which plugin should I use?

Comment: Enable all Spring-based plugins.